# Excel PowerPivot DAX SUMX

Tags: excel, dax, powerpivot

I have an Excel table holding current occupancy and estimated occupancy a week down the line reported by different facilities. Table structure is as following

```
Facility | Start_Date | End_Date |Occupancy_on_Start_Date  | Expected_Occupancy_on_End_Date |
A        |01-07-20    |08-07-20  |05                       |15                              |
A        |08-07-20    |15-07-20  |17                       |09                              |
A        |15-07-20    |22-07-20  |10                       |16                              |
B        |08-07-20    |15-07-20  |16                       |13                              |
```

I have to check the correctness of the estimated occupancy, by comparing the occupancy estimated in one week with actual occupancy reported in the following week. I tried to create a measure in Excel PowerPivot using SUMX and Calculate functions. However, I am not able to get a result, because comparing the values of Start_Date and End_Date in different rows is not possible.

Any thoughts please?

Thanks in advance.....

Comment: Should the 4th row be facility B?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by using SUMIFS function. thanks